# Is there a way to adapt numbas compilation to stop using time for JIT compilation?

Tags: python, compilation, cython, jit, numba

I have some functions on which even numba compilation takes forever (because of the compilation).
Is there a way to get and properly edit the `C(?)` file.
and use it via cython?

Comment: Numba doesn't generate a C file. Even if it did, Cython would need this supposed C file to be compiled in order to use it and thus you would not save any time. I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding both Numba and Cython.

Comment: With that said, I think Numba can now do ahead of time compilation to a compiled extension module (not using C, or Cython). You might want to look this up.

Comment: @DavidW Already red about this, but couldnt understand the decorator pattern,Is there a good example on this?